# how to create view on multiple tables and i want to insert data through triggers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have 5 tables in my database. i want to create view on tables and insert data into tables using triggers and stored procedures.  and if i insert data it should reflect on base tables

```
i have tried creating view on tables 

CREATE DATABASE BankingDB



-- STEP 3: CONNECT TO ABOVE CREATED DATABASE
USE Bankingdb
GO


-- STEP 4: CREATE SCHEMAS IN THE DATABASE TO ORGANIZE THE TABLES

CREATE SCHEMA BANK
GO
CREATE SCHEMA ACCOUNT
GO
CREATE SCHEMA TRANSACTIONS  
GO


-- STEP 5: CREATE TABLES USING ABOVE DEFINED SCHEMAS AND FILEGROUPS
CREATE TABLE BANK.tblBank
(   
    bankId      BIGINT IDENTITY(1000,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    bankDetails VARCHAR(50)
)   

INSERT INTO BANK.tblBank (bankDetails) VALUES ('State Bank of India')
INSERT INTO BANK.tblBank (bankDetails) VALUES ('State Bank of Mysore')
INSERT INTO BANK.tblBank (bankDetails) VALUES ('State Bank of Hyderbad')
INSERT INTO BANK.tblBank (bankDetails) VALUES ('ICICI')
INSERT INTO BANK.tblBank (bankDetails) VALUES ('Punjab Nationnal Bank')
INSERT INTO BANK.tblBank (bankDetails) VALUES ('HDFC')
INSERT INTO BANK.tblBank (bankDetails) VALUES ('IDBI')
INSERT INTO BANK.tblBank (bankDetails) VALUES ('Karnataka Bank')
INSERT INTO BANK.tblBank (bankDetails) VALUES ('Syndicate Bank')
INSERT INTO BANK.tblBank (bankDetails) VALUES ('Canara Bank')
INSERT INTO BANK.tblBank (bankDetails) VALUES ('Citi Bank')
INSERT INTO BANK.tblBank (bankDetails) VALUES ('Wells Fargo')
INSERT INTO BANK.tblBank (bankDetails) VALUES ('Discover')
INSERT INTO BANK.tblBank (bankDetails) VALUES ('TCF')



CREATE TABLE BANK.tbladdAddress
(   
    addId       BIGINT IDENTITY(1000,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    addLine1    VARCHAR(100),
    addLine2    VARCHAR(50),
    addCity     VARCHAR(50),
    addPostCode VARCHAR(15),
    addState    VARCHAR(50), 
    addCountry  VARCHAR(50)
)


    INSERT INTO BANK.tbladdAddress (addLine1,addLine2,addCity,addPostCode,addState,addCountry) VALUES('9730 37th Place North','Apt#204','Plymouth','55441','MN','USA')
    INSERT INTO BANK.tbladdAddress (addLine1,addLine2,addCity,addPostCode,addState,addCountry) VALUES('Kombettu House','Padavu, Ujirpade Post Balnad','Puttur','574203','Karnataka','India')
    INSERT INTO BANK.tbladdAddress (addLine1,addLine2,addCity,addPostCode,addState,addCountry) VALUES('302, Sai Manor Towers','X Roads, SR Nagar','Hyderabad','574038','Andra Pradesh','India')




CREATE TABLE BANK.tblbtBranchType
(   
    btId    BIGINT IDENTITY(1000,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    btTypeCode  VARCHAR(4) ,
    btTypeDesc  VARCHAR(100)

) 


    INSERT INTO BANK.tblbtBranchType (btTypeCode,btTypeDesc) VALUES ('LU','Large Urban')
    INSERT INTO BANK.tblbtBranchType (btTypeCode,btTypeDesc) VALUES ('SR','Small Rural')
    INSERT INTO BANK.tblbtBranchType (btTypeCode,btTypeDesc) VALUES ('HO','Head Office')

CREATE TABLE BANK.tblbrBranch
(
brID                BIGINT IDENTITY (1000,1) PRIMARY KEY,
brBankId_fk         BIGINT references BANK.tblBank (bankId),
brAddress_fk        BIGINT references BANK.tbladdAddress (addId),
brBranchTypeCode_fk BIGINT references BANK.tblbtBranchType (btId),
brBranchName        VARCHAR(100),
brBranchPhone1      VARCHAR(20),
brBranchPhone2      VARCHAR(20),
brBranchFax         VARCHAR(20),
brBranchemail       VARCHAR(50),
brBranchIFSC        VARCHAR(20)
)



ALTER TABLE BANK.tblbrBranch ADD CONSTRAINT FK_brBankId FOREIGN KEY (brBankId_fk) 
REFERENCES BANK.tblBank (bankId)

ALTER TABLE BANK.tblbrBranch ADD CONSTRAINT FK_brAddress FOREIGN KEY (brAddress_fk) 
REFERENCES BANK.tbladdAddress (addId)

ALTER TABLE BANK.tblbrBranch ADD CONSTRAINT FK_brBranchTypeCode FOREIGN KEY (brBranchTypeCode_fk) 
REFERENCES BANK.tblbtBranchType (btId)

    INSERT INTO Bank.tblbrBranch(brAddress_fk,brBankId_fk,brBranchTypeCode_fk,brBranchName,brBranchPhone1,brBranchPhone2,brBranchFax,brBranchemail,brBranchIFSC) VALUES (1000,1011,1001,'Golden Valley','1 323 416 4705','1 323 416 4095','1 763 954 1522','wellsfargogv@wellsfargo.com','WFGV1015')
    INSERT INTO Bank.tblbrBranch(brAddress_fk,brBankId_fk,brBranchTypeCode_fk,brBranchName,brBranchPhone1,brBranchPhone2,brBranchFax,brBranchemail,brBranchIFSC) VALUES (1001,1007,1002,'Mangalore','91 824 247623','91 824 247624','91 824 247625','banker25@karnatakabank.com','KBIN05267')
    INSERT INTO Bank.tblbrBranch(brAddress_fk,brBankId_fk,brBranchTypeCode_fk,brBranchName,brBranchPhone1,brBranchPhone2,brBranchFax,brBranchemail,brBranchIFSC) VALUES (1002,1000,1000,'Puttur Market','91 8251 249246','91 8251 249247','91 8251 249244','sbi.04270@sbi.co.in','SBIN004270')




CREATE TABLE BANK.tblcstCustomer
(   
    cstId            BIGINT  IDENTITY (1000,1),
    cstAddId_fk      BIGINT,
    cstBranchId_fk   BIGINT,
    cstFirstName     VARCHAR(50),
    cstLastName      VARCHAR(50),
    CstMiddleName    VARCHAR(50),
    cstDOB           DATE,
    cstSince         DATETIME,
    cstPhone1        VARCHAR(20),
    cstPhone2        VARCHAR(20),
    cstFax           VARCHAR(20),
    cstGender        VARCHAR(10),
    cstemail         VARCHAR(50)
)

    ALTER TABLE BANK.tblcstCustomer ADD CONSTRAINT PK_cstId PRIMARY KEY (cstId)
    ALTER TABLE BANK.tblcstCustomer ADD CONSTRAINT FK_cstAddId FOREIGN KEY (cstAddId_fk) REFERENCES BANK.tbladdAddress (addId)
    ALTER TABLE BANK.tblcstCustomer ADD CONSTRAINT FK_cstBranchId FOREIGN KEY (cstBranchId_fk) REFERENCES BANK.tblbrBranch (brID)

    INSERT INTO BANK.tblcstCustomer (cstAddId_fk,cstBranchId_fk,cstFirstName,cstLastName,CstMiddleName,cstDOB,cstSince,cstPhone1,cstPhone2,cstFax,cstGender,cstemail) VALUES (1001,1002,'Gaurao','Tarpe','','25-Dec-1986','2000','91 824 247623','','','Male','y')
    INSERT INTO BANK.tblcstCustomer (cstAddId_fk,cstBranchId_fk,cstFirstName,cstLastName,CstMiddleName,cstDOB,cstSince,cstPhone1,cstPhone2,cstFax,cstGender,cstemail) VALUES (1002,1002,'Chaithra','Kunjathaya','Nithin','19-Jan-1990','2005','91 8251 249246','','','Female','y')
    INSERT INTO BANK.tblcstCustomer (cstAddId_fk,cstBranchId_fk,cstFirstName,cstLastName,CstMiddleName,cstDOB,cstSince,cstPhone1,cstPhone2,cstFax,cstGender,cstemail) VALUES (1001,1001,'Adarsh','Hegde','','19-Jan-1990','2015','91 8251 249246','','','Male','y')
    INSERT INTO BANK.tblcstCustomer (cstAddId_fk,cstBranchId_fk,cstFirstName,cstLastName,CstMiddleName,cstDOB,cstSince,cstPhone1,cstPhone2,cstFax,cstGender,cstemail) VALUES (1000,1002,'Nithin','Kumar','','9-Nov-1985','1996','1 323 416 4705','','','Male','y')
    INSERT INTO BANK.tblcstCustomer (cstAddId_fk,cstBranchId_fk,cstFirstName,cstLastName,CstMiddleName,cstDOB,cstSince,cstPhone1,cstPhone2,cstFax,cstGender,cstemail) VALUES (1000,1002,'Nathan','Kamas','','10-Nov-1985','1996','1 323 416 4705','','','Male','y')



CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT.tblaccAccountType
( 
accTypeId BIGINT IDENTITY (1000,1),
accTypeCode VARCHAR(10),
accTypeDesc VARCHAR(100)
)

ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT.tblaccAccountType ADD CONSTRAINT PK_accTypeId 
PRIMARY KEY (accTypeId)


INSERT INTO ACCOUNT.tblaccAccountType VALUES ('CHK','Checking')
INSERT INTO ACCOUNT.tblaccAccountType VALUES ('SAV','Saving')
INSERT INTO ACCOUNT.tblaccAccountType VALUES ('CUR','Current')
INSERT INTO ACCOUNT.tblaccAccountType VALUES ('LN','Loan')




CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT.tblaccAccountStatus
( 
accStatusId BIGINT IDENTITY (1000,1),
accStatusCode VARCHAR(10),
accStatusDesc VARCHAR(50)
)

ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT.tblaccAccountStatus ADD CONSTRAINT 
PK_accStatusId PRIMARY KEY (accStatusId)

INSERT INTO ACCOUNT.tblaccAccountStatus VALUES ('A','Active')
INSERT INTO ACCOUNT.tblaccAccountStatus VALUES ('C','Closed')


CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT.tblaccAccount
( 
accNumber BIGINT IDENTITY (20000,1),
accStatusCode_fk BIGINT,
accTypeCode_fk BIGINT,
accCustomerId_fk BIGINT,
accBalance DECIMAL(26,4)
) 

    ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT.tblaccAccount ADD CONSTRAINT PK_accNumber PRIMARY KEY (accNumber)
    ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT.tblaccAccount ADD CONSTRAINT FK_accStatusCode 
    FOREIGN KEY (accStatusCode_fk) REFERENCES ACCOUNT.tblaccAccountStatus (accStatusId)
    ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT.tblaccAccount ADD CONSTRAINT FK_accTypeCode 
    FOREIGN KEY (accTypeCode_fk) REFERENCES ACCOUNT.tblaccAccountType (accTypeId)
    ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT.tblaccAccount ADD CONSTRAINT FK_accCustomerId 
    FOREIGN KEY (accCustomerId_fk) REFERENCES BANK.tblcstCustomer (cstId)

    INSERT INTO ACCOUNT.tblaccAccount  (accStatusCode_fk,accTypeCode_fk,accCustomerId_fk,accBalance) VALUES (1000,1001,1000,10000)
    INSERT INTO ACCOUNT.tblaccAccount  (accStatusCode_fk,accTypeCode_fk,accCustomerId_fk,accBalance) VALUES (1001,1000,1001,200000.9897)
    INSERT INTO ACCOUNT.tblaccAccount  (accStatusCode_fk,accTypeCode_fk,accCustomerId_fk,accBalance) VALUES (1001,1001,1002,30000.456)
    INSERT INTO ACCOUNT.tblaccAccount  (accStatusCode_fk,accTypeCode_fk,accCustomerId_fk,accBalance) VALUES (1001,1002,1003,5000)
    INSERT INTO ACCOUNT.tblaccAccount  (accStatusCode_fk,accTypeCode_fk,accCustomerId_fk,accBalance) VALUES (1001,1000,1004,500)

CREATE TABLE TRANSACTIONS.tbltranTransactionType
( 
tranCodeID BIGINT IDENTITY (1000,1),
tranTypeDesc VARCHAR(50)
) 

    ALTER TABLE TRANSACTIONS.tbltranTransactionType ADD CONSTRAINT 
    PK_tranCodeID PRIMARY KEY (tranCodeID) 

    INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS.tbltranTransactionType(tranTypeDesc) VALUES ('Deposit')
    INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS.tbltranTransactionType(tranTypeDesc) VALUES ('Withdrawal')

CREATE TABLE TRANSACTIONS.tbltranTransaction
( 
tranID BIGINT IDENTITY 
(1000,1),
tranCode VARCHAR(50),
tranAccountNumber_fk BIGINT,
tranCode_fk BIGINT,
tranDatetime DateTime,
tranTransactionAmount Decimal(26,4),
tranMerchant VARCHAR(50),
tranDescription VARCHAR(50),
RunningBalance DECIMAL(26,4) DEFAULT NULL
) 

    ALTER TABLE TRANSACTIONS.tbltranTransaction ADD CONSTRAINT PK_tranID PRIMARY KEY (tranID) 
    ALTER TABLE TRANSACTIONS.tbltranTransaction ADD CONSTRAINT 
    FK_tranAccountNumber FOREIGN KEY (tranAccountNumber_fk) REFERENCES ACCOUNT.tblaccAccount (accNumber)
    ALTER TABLE TRANSACTIONS.tbltranTransaction ADD CONSTRAINT 
    FK_tranCode FOREIGN KEY (tranCode_fk) REFERENCES TRANSACTIONS.tbltranTransactionType (tranCodeID)
    ALTER TABLE TRANSACTIONS.tbltranTransaction ADD CONSTRAINT DF_tranDatetime DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR tranDatetime 
    ALTER TABLE TRANSACTIONS.tbltranTransaction ADD CONSTRAINT DF_tranCode DEFAULT NEWID() FOR tranCode

    INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS.tbltranTransaction (tranAccountNumber_fk,tranCode_fk,tranTransactionAmount,tranMerchant,tranDescription) VALUES (20000,1000,20500.456,'Self','Self Deposit')
    INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS.tbltranTransaction (tranAccountNumber_fk,tranCode_fk,tranTransactionAmount,tranMerchant,tranDescription) VALUES (20001,1001,200000,'Discover','Withdrawal')
    INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS.tbltranTransaction (tranAccountNumber_fk,tranCode_fk,tranTransactionAmount,tranMerchant,tranDescription) VALUES (20000,1001,13.45,'','Cheque #5001')
    INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS.tbltranTransaction (tranAccountNumber_fk,tranCode_fk,tranTransactionAmount,tranMerchant,tranDescription) VALUES (20001,1000,2500,'Self','Self Deposit')
    INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS.tbltranTransaction (tranAccountNumber_fk,tranCode_fk,tranTransactionAmount,tranMerchant,tranDescription) VALUES (20001,1000,25000,'Discover','Withdrawal')
    INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS.tbltranTransaction (tranAccountNumber_fk,tranCode_fk,tranTransactionAmount,tranMerchant,tranDescription) VALUES (20001,1001,200000,'Discover','Withdrawal')
    INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS.tbltranTransaction (tranAccountNumber_fk,tranCode_fk,tranTransactionAmount,tranMerchant,tranDescription) VALUES (20003,1000,20500.456,'Self','Self Deposit')
    INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS.tbltranTransaction (tranAccountNumber_fk,tranCode_fk,tranTransactionAmount,tranMerchant,tranDescription) VALUES (20004,1001,200000,'Discover','Withdrawal')
    INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS.tbltranTransaction (tranAccountNumber_fk,tranCode_fk,tranTransactionAmount,tranMerchant,tranDescription) VALUES (20001,1000,20500.456,'Self','Self Deposit')
    INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS.tbltranTransaction (tranAccountNumber_fk,tranCode_fk,tranTransactionAmount,tranMerchant,tranDescription) VALUES (20003,1001,25000,'Discover','Withdrawal')

select * from TRANSACTIONS.tbltranTransaction
select newid()

-- SYNONYMS ARE PERMENANT ALTERNATE NAMES TO TABLES / ANY DATABASE OBJECTS
CREATE SYNONYM synBank                  FOR BANK.tblBank
CREATE SYNONYM synAddress               FOR BANK.tbladdAddress
CREATE SYNONYM synBranchType            FOR BANK.tblbtBranchType
CREATE SYNONYM synBranch                FOR BANK.tblbrBranch
CREATE SYNONYM synCustomer              FOR BANK.tblcstCustomer
CREATE SYNONYM synAccountType           FOR ACCOUNT.tblaccAccountType
CREATE SYNONYM synAccountStatus         FOR ACCOUNT.tblaccAccountStatus
CREATE SYNONYM synAccount               FOR ACCOUNT.tblaccAccount
CREATE SYNONYM synTransactionType       FOR TRANSACTIONS.tbltranTransactionType  
CREATE SYNONYM synTransaction           FOR TRANSACTIONS.tbltranTransaction'
```

I want to create view these tables and i want to create trigger on the view, so that if i insert some data through view then the base table should get updated.through triggers if we update views then the base table should reflect the inserts.

I want to create views and triggers for these tables tblbank,tblbrbranch,tblbtbranchtype,tbladdaddress,tblcstcustomer

Comment: `i have tried creating view on tables` Can you show us what you have tried ?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this? https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/236425/How-to-Insert-Data-Using-SQL-Views-Created-Using-M it's not really clear from your question.

Comment: You don't create any Views in your sample, so this is hard to answer right now. If the view is a simple view, however, then you can `INSERT` into the `VIEW` and the underlying table will be updated without needing an `INSTEAD OF` Trigger. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e46ff1eaa6fc2a8de3ddf2b632cbdf61)

Comment: Well that's nice. Please post back when you run into a problem with which you need help solving. SO is not a free code writing service.